# Call parametrised constructor in enum singleton?

Tags: java, enums

I have this enum singleton class:

```
enum C1 {
    INSTANCE("");

    C1(String s) {
        System.out.println("with param = " +s);
    }
    C1() {
        System.out.println("without param");
    }   
    public void g() {
        System.out.println("inside g");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        C1.INSTANCE.g();
        C1.INSTANCE.g();

    }
}
```

How can i call `C1(String s)` constructor using `INSTANCE` by passing custom parameter ?

Comment: You already are calling the constructor which takes a string.

Comment: You can't manually call an enum constructor. It is done automatically when the enum constants are created.

Comment: `INSTANCE` is static instance created using some constructor (in you case `C1(String s)`). You cannot call constructor for already created object. 

What is the real problem behind this question?

Comment: C1(String s) is getting called by how can i pass custom parameter here? like INSTANCE("hello") is possible?

Comment: You cannot manually initialize an instance *at all*.  This is part of what an `enum` is about.  The declared enum identifiers identify singleton objects that have properties defined *by the enum*, not by its clients.  You just use them, by name.

Comment: `INSTANCE("hello")` creates static instance and you cannot re-initialize it. You can add parameter to `g()` function. What is the real problem behind this question?

Comment: You can not create new enum instances on-demand. The constructor is `private`. Enums must be well-defined. You can not *add* new entries to it at runtime. Rethink your design and if you truly want enums.

Comment: As constructor is getting called once so i thought that having parametised constructer will allow me to initialize only once with custom params.

Answer (score 2):

You can have someting like that

```
    enum C1 {
        WITH_PARAM("value"),
        EMPTY();

        private String value;
        C1(String s) {
            System.out.println("with param = " +s);
            value=s;
        }
        C1() {
            System.out.println("without param");
        }
        public void g() {
            System.out.println("inside g, value is "+value);
        }
    }

        public static void main(String s[]) {
            C1.EMPTY.g();
            C1.WITH_PARAM.g();

        }
```

Comment: Can i send params dynamically??

Comment: To constructor? It creates singleton so you can send parameters but just one time. For example, you can initialize using environment variable so at some degree it will be "dynamically"

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can use class type, not enum type. Enums are intended to be static and final. The idea of the enum constructor is to encapsulate several values so you can use them after by setting only one type of enum.

```
public enum Vehicle {
    CAR(4, 2),
    TRUCK(6, 20);

    private Integer numOfTyres;
    private Integer maxWeight;

    Vehicle(Integer numOfTyres, Integer maxWeight) {
        this.numOfTyres = numOfTyres;
        this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
        System.out.println("Number of Tyres = " + numOfTyres);
        System.out.println("Max weight = " + maxWeight);
    }


    public Integer getMaxWeight() {
         return maxWeight;
    }

    public Integer getNumberOfTyres() {
        return numOfTyres;
    }

}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        Vehicle.CAR.getNumberOfTyres();

        for (Vehicle v : Vehicle.values()) {
            System.out.println();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Vehicle ");
            sb.append(v.name());
            sb.append(" has ");
            sb.append(v.getNumberOfTyres());
            sb.append(" number of tyres and ");
            sb.append(v.getMaxWeight());
            sb.append(" max weight ");


            System.out.println("-----------------");
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            System.out.println("-----------------");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: An enum instance _is_ a class instance. In fact, Effective Java suggests using `enum` as the preferred way to implement singletons. The several constructors in the OP don't make sense in this case of course.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know - the constructor for an enum type must be package-private or private access.

It is called automatically and creates the constants that are defined at the beginning of the enum body.

You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself.

Here are some examples that might be helpful.

```
public enum MySingleton {
    // if you have multiple constants here - it's not Singleton
    INSTANCE;

    // if you need to provide some info to your INSTANCE,
    // you can add params to its methods
    public void someMethod(String value) {
        System.out.println("inside someMethod, value is " +value);
    }
}
```

If you need the instance to have some state you can add fields and a constructor:

```
public enum MySingleton {
    INSTANCE("Hello");

    private String message;

    MySingleton(String msg) {
        this.message = msg;
    }

    // you can even have getter/setter for it
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Main method sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MySingleton.INSTANCE.getMessage()); // prints Hello

    MySingleton.INSTANCE.setMessage("Bye");

    System.out.println(MySingleton .INSTANCE.getMessage()); // prints Bye
}
```